# sending data AJAX post data to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

I'm having the hardest time sending the value of a dropdown(as html) to my controller, should be pretty straightforward..

### the select dropdown :

```
<select id="form_selection">
  <option value="Home School">Home School</option>
  <option value="teem">teem</option>
</select>
```

### Javascript

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form_selection').change(function() {
    var selection = $(this).find(":selected").text();
    console.log(selection);

     $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/retrieve_form_template/',
      async: false,
      type: 'POST',
      data: selection,
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      }
      });



   }); //end ajax

    });//end function
    </script>
```

### the controller:

```
public function retrieve_form_template() 
{
$selection = $this->input->post('selection');
echo var_dump($selection);
}
```

i get bool(false) as the returned value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
var selection = $(this).find(":selected").html();
```

with

```
var selection = $(this).val();
```

Your ajax call will be like

```
$.ajax({
   url: '<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/retrieve_form_template/',
   async: false,
   type: 'POST',
   data: {selection : selection},
   dataType: 'html',
   success: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: same result no value send over =/

Comment: That works can you explain to me what was happening?

Comment: Here we have assigned selection value to a variable selection that will be posted on your page...That's it

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following change with jQuery ajax function

data: 'selection='+selection,